# JSON returned from Memcache is invalid

Tags: php, json, drupal-7, memcached

I have `Drupal 7` site. I am using `Memcache` for caching.

This is how I am storing the JSON into it

```
    //creating an object of Memcache
    $cache = new Memcache();
    $cache ->addServer('localhost', 11211);
    //adding a key
    $cacheKey = 'mobile';
    //delete old cache
    $cache ->delete($cacheKey);
    //refresh cache
    $cache ->set($cacheKey, serialize($jsonData));
```

No issue till here. But when fetching the JSON from this cache.

**returned JSON fails to validate**

I am using `http://jsonlint.com/` to validate my JSON.

Please note the however the JSON has correct data but issue is validation.

```
$Records = $cache->get($cacheKey);

echo '<pre>';
print_r(Records);
exit();
```

Any help highly appreciated.

**JSON returned on var_dump() as mentioned in ans by Jeroen**

```
string '{"defaults":[{"nid":"213","public_url":"http:\/\/www.mywebsite.com","current_ver'... (length=3033)
```

Comment: That output is not really helpful as part of a json string is always invalid.

Comment: any other way to fix this

Comment: How can anybody help you fix this if you refuse to show the input and output you are getting?

Comment: @jeroen I tried with strip_tag(), it resolves the error. But I don't want to remove <p> from my string.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `serialize()` when you store your data, so you need to use `unserialize()` when you get it:

```
$cache->set($cacheKey, serialize($jsonData));

...

$jsonData = unserialize($cache->get($cacheKey));
```

Although there is not really any need to serialize the data as Memcache will take care of that:

```
$cache->set($cacheKey, $jsonData);

...

$jsonData = $cache->get($cacheKey);
```

**Edit:**

To see what you have exactly:

```
var_dump($cacheKey);
var_dump($jsonData);
$cache->set($cacheKey, $jsonData);

...

$jsonData = $cache->get($cacheKey);
var_dump($cacheKey);
var_dump($jsonData);
```

Comment: checekd. still same issue

Comment: @pkhode You should remove the `serialize` / `unserialize` completely. And of course you need to make sure you are using the correct key.

Comment: Both things checked.as you mentioned still issue persists

Comment: Please note the JSON has some HTML strings values stored in it

Comment: @pkhode You should add `var_dump()`'s of the data before and the data after. They should be the same :-)

Comment: Because when I am doing it, It has prepended "string" to json

Comment: @pkhode See my edit, can you add that below your question?

Comment: How do I get rid of it.Please suggest